# Unable to play audio when navigating to new page

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

i am trying to play an audio in my flutter application when the page is navigated to. i am unable to do so. furthermore, i found out that i am not even able to play the audio via a button as well. i have included the error logs below. any help would be greatly appreciated. tia

```
  final flipPlayer = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    flipPlayer.play(AssetSource('sounds/flip.mp3'));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    flipPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

```
W/Parcel  (30201): Expecting binder but got null!
V/MediaPlayer(30201): resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
V/MediaPlayer(30201): cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
```